# How to add first and second row of each pair of rows in dataframe to separate list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, dataframe

So I have a dataframe which looks like the following:

Out of every pair of rows eg 0&1, 2&3, 4&5, 6&7 etc, I would like to add each row to a separate list. Each number is a time and I am then doing a-b to compute the reaction time. How does one do this?

```
Index      Time
0          70
1          75.3
2          76 
3          79.7
4          82 
5          84.2
```

I can do the next part using the following code:

```
reaction_times = []
for i in list(zip(a,b)):
    rt = b-a
    reaction_times.append(rt)
```

Thank you!

EDIT: The output I would like is essentially a list of reaction times (a is the first value and b is the second value for each pair of times (each referring to the start & end of a trial)). However, if there is a way to do: [(75.3-70), (79.7-76), (84.2-82)] and so forth, this would also be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mind to provide a full [mcve](/help/mcve)? What's the output you are looking for? What are `a` and `b`?

Comment: I don't understand what it is you want.  I get that you want to group by pairs.  That can be accomplished with `df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 2)`.  I just don't get what you want after that.  Try to provide your expected result as well.

Comment: Hi! I have added an edit explaining what the end result should be, sorry about not having included it earlier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to subtract the second value from the first value, you can use the following code.

```
dfgrouped = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2)

dfgrouped.last()-dfgrouped.first()
```

Comment: copy and paste of @pIRSquared 's comment? Frowned upon :(

Comment: Not what happened

Comment: alright, that's good then. It does happen quite often, so I'm glad you didn't :) Apologies for the "accusation". Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to find the difference between `odd` and `even` data points.

```py
df.Time[1::2].reset_index(drop=True) - df.Time[0::2].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output

```
0    5.3
1    3.7
2    2.2
```

Answer (score 1):

rolling() method.

```
df.Time.rolling(2).apply(lambda x : x[1] - x[0],raw=True)[1:].tolist()
```

output

```
[5.299999999999997,
 0.7000000000000028,
 3.700000000000003,
 2.299999999999997,
 2.200000000000003]
```